# Versioning of associated content, Sitecore 8.2 initial

Tags: versions

**Scenario:** I'm on a page in Experience Editor. The page consists of some components in them.

**Step 1:** I press "Lock and edit" in the notifications.

**Step 2:** I now edit in a component on the page and save.

A new version is added to the ***component & page***.

Now both the old and the new version of the page point to the new version of the component. Which isn't the result I'm expecting.

Why does version 1 of the ***page*** have version 2 of the component?

What I want is versions of the ***page*** to remember what versions they had of their renderings data source.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not how Sitecore works. Sitecore layout fields do not include the information about datasource version. And this cannot be changed easily.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be standard behavior for Sitecore.  Having said that, there is a setting called **WebEdit.EditAllVersions**.  By default, it is set to **true**.  I've not experimented with changing this to false but you could try that.  The comments for this setting read:

```
<!--
  WEB EDIT ALL VERSIONS
            Allows switch to the shared layout of the page.
            Default value: true

-->
<setting name="WebEdit.EditAllVersions" value="true" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
```

This might be related to the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: That setting just switches whether Shared or Final layout can be edited in the Experience Editor, it will not affect versioning.